# Copy vector of object to vector of shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, vector, move

I have a simple struct and vector of its objects.
And I want to move all objects to the vector of shared_ptrs.
I don't need the initial vector anymore.
I presented you with my situation.

Is my approach correct? I want to do this the most effective way:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i_;
    std::string s_;
};

void copyVector(std::vector< MyStruct>&& vt)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>> ptrsVt;


    for (auto& v : vt)
        ptrsVt.push_back(std::make_shared<MyStruct>(std::move(v)));

    // ...
}

void processing()
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> vt = getVectorFromSomewhere();

    copyVector(std::move(vt));
}
```

Comment: "effective" means that it does what it is should to do. I suppose you mean "efficient"

Comment: `copyVector` is the wrong name for a function that moves from a vector

Comment: Note `copyVector` is a void function that only takes in the source vector. How do you expect the result vector be used afterwards?

Comment: Yep, copyVector is incorrect a bit. Let's call it moveVector.
It is excerpt of the my code, I just need to move it somehow, but vector of shred_ptrs is a class member

Comment: I always trigger on shared_ptr's :) So I am curious as to why you would need a vector of shared_pointers in the first place. By moving the objects into the vector you seem to imply it takes ownership of the data. Why keep individual shared_ptrs? Almost the only reason I use shared_ptr's is to extend lifetime of objects when I pass them to background threads.

Comment: For me this is XY Problem. Why introducing extra indirection? To increase number of cache misses?

Comment: @MarekR It is possible that this is an API requirement, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. You might want to `reserve` the size of the destination beforehand though:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
auto transform_vector(std::vector<T>&& src) -> std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> dst;
  dst.reserve(src.size());

  transform(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dst),
            [](T& elm) { return std::make_shared<T>(std::move(elm)); });

  return dst;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> elms{"a", "b", "c"};
  auto ptrs = transform_vector(std::move(elms));

  for (auto const& elm : elms) {
    std::printf("\"%s\", ", elm.c_str());  // moved strings, possibly empty
  }

  std::putchar('\n');

  for (auto const& ptr : ptrs) {
    std::printf("\"%s\", ", ptr->c_str());  // "a", "b", "c"
  }

  std::putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Yep, 'reserve' is necessary. Thanks!